# Find the difference between all integers in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration, difference

I have an array of integers in Ruby. I want to find the differences between each number and every other number.

I can do it with one of the integers and find the difference between it and all the other numbers but I can't work out how to iterate twice per se.

Here is what I have:

```
def stock_picker(ary)
  ary.map {|a| ary[0] - a }
end

stock_picker [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#=> [0, -1, -2, -3, -4]
```

When I run the above for `ary[1]` instead of `ary[0]` I get:

```
[1, 0, -1, -2, -3]
```

For `ary[2]` it's:

```
[2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
```

and so on. But How can I generate the differences for all numbers in `ary` regardless of its size?

The expected result is:

```
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: What does "find the difference between all of them" mean? That makes no sense. A "difference" is always between exactly two entities. What would the result be for `[]`? What would the result be for `[0]`? What would the result be for `[-1]`? What would the result be for `[1]`? What would the result be for `[0, 0, 0]`? What would the result be for `[-1, -1, -1]`? What would the result be for `[1, 1, 1]`? What would the result be for `[-1, 0, 1]`? What would the result be for `[1, 0, -1]`? What would the result be for `[0, -1, 1]`? What would the result be for `[1, 2, 3]`? …

Comment: What would the result be for `[2, 1, 3]`? What would the result be for `[2, 3, 1]`? What would the result be for `[3, 2, 1]`? What would the result be in the general case for `[a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, … a_n]`? Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, etc?

Comment: The difference is the result when you subtract one number from another

Comment: @Tessumi but you have multiple numbers and it's not clear which of them gets subtracted from which other number. For example, what would be the result for `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`? (and why)

Comment: "The difference is the result when you subtract one number from another" – Exactly. The difference is computed between **exactly two** numbers. You are asking "I want to find the difference between **all of them**". This can *only* work if there are *exactly two* numbers in your array. But your array has example array has five numbers.

Comment: @Tessumi you showed the result for the code that you already have. I meant the result that you actually want. You say _"same thing for every index, not just ary[0]"_ – how would _that_ result look like?

Comment: I don't think you have a programming problem here. One of the most important things to understand about programming is that *computers are infinitely stupid*. They are infinitely literal. They cannot guess. They cannot estimate. They cannot take context into account. They have no creativity. They have no intelligence. They cannot ask clarifying questions. They cannot extrapolate from incomplete information. Humans can do all of that. They can ask clarifying questions. They can make inferences, they have context, etc.

Comment: What this means is that **if you cannot even explain your problem to a human, then you have no chance writing a program for it**. But also, **if you cannot even explain your problem to a human, then it is very likely the issue is not a programming problem but rather that you yourself don't understand the problem sufficiently enough to write a program**. In this particular case, you have two humans who are both doing their best trying to understand your problem, asking clarifying questions, applying their knowledge, expertise, and experience, **and can't figure out what you want**.

Comment: There is absolutely no chance that a computer can either, if humans can't. Writing a program is essentially the same as explaining your problem to a computer. Explaining to a computer is much harder than explaining to a human. You have to do the latter first before you can even attempt the former.

Comment: So the output I want is 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 1 0 -1 -2 -3 2 1 0 -1 -2 3 2 1 0 -1 4 3 2 1 0 but nevermind. Maybe this isn't something you can do. I'll try to think of a different way

Comment: Can you provide a precise specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, etc? What would the result be for []? What would the result be for [0]? What would the result be for [-1]? What would the result be for [1]? What would the result be for [0, 0, 0]? What would the result be for [-1, -1, -1]?

Comment: What would the result be for [1, 1, 1]? What would the result be for [-1, 0, 1]? What would the result be for [1, 0, -1]? What would the result be for [0, -1, 1]? What would the result be for [1, 2, 3]? What would the result be for [2, 1, 3]? What would the result be for [2, 3, 1]? What would the result be for [3, 2, 1]? What would the result be in the general case for [a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, … a_n]?

Comment: @Tessumi _"So the output I want is [...]"_ – comments can easily be overlooked. You should [edit] your question to add relevant details.

Comment: @Jörg, You said, "... if you cannot even explain your problem to a human, then you have no chance writing a program for it." It follows that if you can explain your problem to a cat you may be able to write a program for it, though I recognize that most coders do not report to a cat.

Comment: @Stefan thankyou. I appreciate your help. I now know how to write a better question.

Answer (score 2):

More compact version:

```
arr.product(arr).map { |a,b| a - b }
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, this works perfectly. I wish I could upvote you but I just joined stack overflow. Hope you have the best day!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want the following.

```
def doit(arr)
  arr.flat_map { |n| arr.map { |m| n-m } }
end
```

```
doit [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  #=> [0, -1, -2, -3, -4, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, 2, 1,
  #    0, -1, -2, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).